# PHP Yahoo no data returned

Tags: php, yahoo-finance

I'm trying the following by localhost/quote.php?symbol=IBM but $data is coming back empty on  line 42 where it says missing data.

```
<?php



 // require ?symbol=...

 if (empty($_GET["symbol"]))

 {

 trigger_error("Missing symbol", E_USER_ERROR);

 }




 echo $_GET["symbol"];

 $_GET["symbol"] = "IBM";


 // headers for proxy servers

 $headers = [

 "Accept" => "*/*",

 "Connection" => "Keep-Alive",

 "User-Agent" => sprintf("curl/%s", curl_version()["version"])

 ];



 // open connection to Yahoo

 $context = stream_context_create([

 "http" => [

 "header" => implode(array_map(function($value, $key) {return sprintf("%s:  %s\r\n", $key, $value); }, $headers,

 array_keys($headers))),

 "method" => "GET"

 ]

 ]);

 $handle =    fopen("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=snl1&s=  {$_GET["symbol"]}", "r", false, $context);

 if ($handle === false)

 {

 trigger_error("Could not connect to Yahoo!", E_USER_ERROR);

 }





 // download first line of CSV file

 $data = fgetcsv($handle);
 print_r($data);

 if ($data === false || count($data) == 1)

 {

 trigger_error("Missing data", E_USER_ERROR);

 }



 // close connection to Yahoo

 fclose($handle);



 // ensure symbol was found

 if ($data[2] === "0.00")

 {

 trigger_error("Missing price", E_USER_ERROR);

 }



 // prepare stock as an associative array

 $stock = [

 "symbol" => $data[0],

 "name" => $data[1],

 "price" => floatval($data[2])] ;

 // output stock as JSON

 header

("Content-Type: application/json");

 print(json_encode($stock));



 ?>
```

Comment: line 42 being what, this? `&s=  {$_GET["symbol"]}"` - seems to be some GET parameters missing. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and you may want to `trim()` that, for the space in there.

Comment: the trim did the trick, thanks

Comment: great, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL contains spaces:

```
fopen("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=snl1&s=  {$_GET["symbol"]}",
                                                               ^^
```

You need to `trim()` it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); // you could also use '-1' to get all errors.
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

- `var_dump()`'ing is another tool you can use during development

Comment: Great answer, just had to ruin that perfect rep ;P

Comment: @Darren hahahaha!! yeah I saw that. Seeing that perfect 55,000 this morning was pretty cool, got a double nickel ;-) No worries buddy, cheers and thanks.

Comment: You jumped all the way up since the last time I saw your rep! It's impressive sir! Congrat ;-)

Comment: @Darren Must've been quite a while Darren. Lordie, I don't submit that many answers often now, only the *sure bets* and *clear* questions. I get a few residuals and that's good.

Comment: @Darren thanks for the edit. My browser's starting to act up on me and I think it's sending me a message to hit the hay. ciao for now ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: Couldn't resist myself ;-) Catch ya later sir!